# Xamarin Forms Google Maps

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

acabo de crear una App en Xamarin Forms la cual va a tener un mapa de google en la visual principal. Y al emular el dispositivo y correr la aplicación en debug me aparece una pantalla completamente azul con el texto Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps en medio de la pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque se puede ocacionar esto?

Comment: Me parece que te hace falta una api key, leiste la doc?

Comment: La tengo agregada a la api key, y en la consola de google cloud esta habilitada